# How to define this in a constructor function

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = 'global';
var b = function() {
  var a = 'scoped';
  new Function('console.log(a)')();
}
b();
```

Code above will log `'global'`, what should I do to log `'scoped'` instead?

Comment: Frankly: Don't use the Function constructor. It's eval by another name and has all the associated problems. Find a solution to the underlying problem that doesn't involve eval.

Comment: @Quentin thank you, this is a question that somebody asked me for fun. It's surely wired and unusual, but I am curious how to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. Calling the constructor directly can create functions dynamically, but suffers from security and similar (but far less significant) performance issues to eval. However, unlike eval, the Function constructor creates functions which execute in the global scope only.

Since your problem is about trying to access a variable that **isn't** in the global scope: You can't.

Look for a solution to the underlying problem that doesn't involve `new Function`.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the [`Function` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> However, **unlike eval**, the Function constructor creates functions which execute in the global scope only.

```
  eval("console.log(a)");
```